# How to fix my pen drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a Toshiba Pen Drive.

Whenever I plug it to a computer, it shows a message saying-

> You need to format the drive before you can use it.

I have tried repairing it via the command prompt way as listed in this site:

[How to repair Pen Drive](http://globaltechnoguru.weebly.com/how-to-repair-pen-drive.html)

Diskpart>List Disk> Select Disk 2>Clean

But again the computer returns an error during the 'Clean' command. It says that the action cannot be completed because of an I/O error.

I have tried using **Acronis Disk Director** to create a partition in the pen drive and recover it but to no avail.

I have tried using a software called **Find and Mount** to recover a partition but again to no avail.

I tried using google. Cannot seem to find any other way. Please help!!

Comment: Can you not right click on it and select format?

Comment: Did you try formatting it as it suggests?  Does it do this in every computer you plug it into (more than 1)?

Comment: @Dave rook -> Even after formatting once, it shows the same message again. Hence renders the device useless.

techie007: Yes. I tried it in more than one computer. Shows the same message each time.

Comment: Sounds like it is broken. You could buy a new one (I will assume that you have no files on it since you did the reformat)...

Comment: Smash drive.  Drop in trash.  Buy new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really sounds like that drive is toast.  If you can't format it with a utility like the HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool then it's likely to not be repairable.

Here is the link to the format tool however I don't think it will do any good if diskpart is failing to fix things.
http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html

Comment: It says "Device media is write-protected".

Any other suggestions or ways to fix it?

Comment: In diskpart you can clear the attributes by selecting the disk then typing "attribute disk clear"

Comment: ^did not help. shows the same message-> Media is write protected and there was some i/o error while cleaning.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  He's dead Jim.